# Unable to run Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I went through a very long installation process to install Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 Enterprise (1607). But when I attempt to run Visual Studio after the installation and the requested reboot, I get the normal Visual Studio banner momentarily, about a second or so, then it goes away and a few seconds later I get an error dialog stating:

```
Could not start visual studio due to an error.
System.InvalidOperationException:
Controller is not responding to incoming requests.
```

I completely uninstalled and tried reinstalling and see the same error. I also ran Visual Studio Installer and selected "repair" which took a long time doing something, then said it finished. But the same problem persists.

Anyone else seen this and know of a solution? I've done quite a bit of Googling but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Did you meet any error message during VS installation? Please have a try 1. Run VS as admin 2. Run VS with safe mode 3. Clean up the folder %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx 4. Perform a clean boot https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows to test. If this issue persists, run devenv /log to collect the activity file and share it.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I did not get any error messages at all other than the one I posted. Installation appeared to go 100% smoothly. I will try the suggestions you made and report back.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT running as administrator, VS runs. After that, I was able to run it as a normal user. But when I tried to create a WPF project, and when it gets to the "loading designer..." screen, it crashes with an unhandled exception: `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException` and `Failed to read from IPC Port: The pipe has been ended.`. If I run as administrator, this problem does not occur. But as a normal user, it continues to occur.

Comment: Did you install the VS using the admin user or normal user, or it installed on the system driver C:? You can have a try with clean up the cache folder C:\Users\v-yuliu1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx\Designer

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I tried installing as normal user, but it prompted for Admin credentials. I am doing this on my work PC which doesn't allow normal users as admin, but has a program for elevating privileges for installs. So I ran the install with elevated privileges. This worked for me on Windows 7. But when my client PC was changed to Windows 10, then I ran into this issue. Target for installation is all default, so drive C:. I'll try cleaning the cache folder.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I cleaned out the cache folder that you suggested, but I still observe the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean you perform the same installation process on your work PC (win 7) and client PC(Win 10), only the client PC meet this issue? To install and modify the VS installation, we need to use the admin permission: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio, please run this tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed and repair the VS 2017 on the computer that has this issue to have a try.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Sorry for my confusing comment. I meant to say that I ran exactly the same installation procedure (using a program that elevates privileges) on a Windows 7 client and had not issue. On my Windows 10 client, I ran into this issue. Attempting to install as a user prompts for admin credentials. I don't have them, but have a tool (Defendpoint) for elevated privileges to install a program, so I used that to do the installation. Unfortunately, I can't seem to run the linked tool with Defendpoint since it's a cab file and not technically an executable (msi or exe).

Comment: Do you have the administrator account on the Win 10 client computer? Please try to uninstall the VS 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio and then sign in with the administrator account to re-install it, it can help us to check if the account permission causes this issue.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I do not have an administrator account. I only have the program that allows me to run an installation with elevated privileges.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I finally got it working properly. I went through your links and first ran the VS installer program with elevated privileges and did the uninstall from there. Then I did another uninstall from the Defendpoint add/remove programs (since it didn't know it was completely uninstalled, having done it independently). I checked cache folders after that to make sure there were none around and rebooted. After rebooting, I reinstalled using Defendpoint elevated privileges. This time, I chose default settings for install packages. That all went fine and it works.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that your issue is solved, please add a reply with your solution and mark it, then will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to easier search this helpful information, thanks.