# Azure function shows "Controller is not responding to incoming requests"

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, azure-functions

I am tired of this error, I wanted to do something else but I end up stuck in this error now.

if anybody knows please help.

[image]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-start-visual-studio-due-to-an-/1366082

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959785/unable-to-run-visual-studio-community-2017-on-windows-10-enterprise last few comments in this question are useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [developer community news](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.9#from-developer-community-7),

`controller is not responding to incoming requests` is the issue of VS 2019 16.9.3 version. And it had fixed in the 16.9.4. If your VS Version is 16.9.3, make a update in your IDE and check once